# Is there any app interaction detector in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, dart

I am developing a flutter app where I want to display an Alert when there is no interaction with the app for some time (say 5 mins). How do I achieve this?

Comment: `GestureBinding.instance.pointerRouter.addGlobalRoute((event) => print(event));` - add it to `main()`and it will print all your touch event interactions - what you will do with that is up to you

Comment: @pskink this comment help me lot i am searching for type of functionality for a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

1. setup a variable and initialize it with current time
2. setup a [timer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html) that tick for every second.
3. when ever user interact with your app, (Gesture, button click etc.) simply update the current time to the variable that we setup on the step 1.
4. on each timer tick, check the difference between the current time and the time we noted on step 1 is equal to or grater than 5 mins, then present the dialog box to the user as per your requirement.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a widget that contains a GestureDetector to detect all user actions with the screen

```dart
class UserActivityDetector extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const UserActivityDetector({super.key, required this.child});
  @override
  State<UserActivityDetector> createState() => _UserActivityDetectorState();
}

class _UserActivityDetectorState extends State<UserActivityDetector> {
  Timer? _timer;
  final duration = const Duration(minutes: 5);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _resetTimer();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _resetTimer() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = Timer(duration, () async {
    //show alert
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () => _resetTimer(),
      onPanDown: (details) => _resetTimer(),
      onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) => _resetTimer(),
      onVerticalDragEnd: (details) => _resetTimer(),
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

2. Wrap Widget in runApp in main()  with UserActivityDetector

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(UserActivityDetector(child: MyApp()));
}
```

3. Every 5 minutes of inactivity, the function in the timer will run
   You will therefore be able to display your Dialog