# Flutter Inactivity catcher

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to add an "inactivity catcher" on an existing app. What i mean by inatctivity catcher is : a mean to detect when the user don't touch the screen during a certain laps of time.

I tryed to wrap my app in a GestureDetector but :

1 - When the something under the widget is rebuilt, the tap are not detected anymore.

2 - When the user tap on an interactive widget (ex: a button or a textfield) the tap is not caught by the GestureDetector on top of the app.

How am I supposed to do ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: see `PointerRouter.addGlobalRoute`

Comment: thank you, Ifound a way to use it in this post : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60088741/is-there-any-app-interaction-detector-in-flutter)

Comment: sorry but the accepted answer is not what you really want

Comment: it was your comment which was helpfull on how to use `PointerRouter.addGlobalRoute`